# Why is my Point Light not creating shadows?

Tags: shaders, light, shadows

I cannot get the shadows to work for this coin. The Power is at 1000000, and the radius is 0.1. I've tried moving the light source, changing the radius, changing the power amount. Nothing has worked so far.
[image: The Power is at 1000000, radius is 0.1.]

Comment: Look at the top-right of your viewport (just above the colored axis indicators) - there are 4 little circles - these represent the different preview modes (left to right - wireframe, solid, material preview, rendered preview). By default, the shading tab uses "material preview" which uses it's own lighting. Select the farthest right circle to enter rendered preview mode to see your lighting.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the shading now. But the coin is all brown, and the light is pure white. I turned the Power down to 1, and radius down to 0, and its still happening.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You said you can see the shading on the coin, but it's not casting a shadow itself? What color/shade do you have your world environment? The light from environment might be too bright. Only other thing I can think to do is enable "contact shadows" under the shadows section of the light properties tab.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The second part didn't work, but I tried to do the first thing you told me to do, and it worked. I apparently didn't turn the light down all the way.